# How to stop fullpage.js scroll when overlay open?

Tags: javascript, fullpage.js

I am trying to stop full page.js scroll when overlay is open

This is the code required to stop scrolling, however, I am not familiar enough with JS to implement this

```
//disabling scrolling
fullpage_api.setAllowScrolling(false);
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
<div class="menu">
  <a href="#" class="menu-link">
  <span class="hamburger-icon">
    <span class="hamburger-bar hamburger-bar-1"></span>
    <span class="hamburger-bar hamburger-bar-3"></span>
  </span>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="menu-overlay">
  <nav class="overlay-menu">
  </nav>
</div>


$(document).ready(function() {

$(".menu-link").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
$(".menu-overlay").toggleClass("open");
  $(".menu").toggleClass("open");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are initializing fullpage.js with jQuery you can use `$.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(false)`.

If you are initializing with plain JS, you need to maintain a reference to the initialized instance. For example:

```
var fullpageapi = new fullpage('#fullpage', {
//options here
    autoScrolling:true,
});
```

Then you can use `fullpageapi.setAllowScrolling(false);` in any scope in which the `fullpageapi` variable is accessible.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Could you possibly show me a working example? Unsure how to initialise this with my code

Comment: It is not required to maintain an instance :) `fullpage_api` is a property of `window` and therefore it is globally available.

Comment: @Sasha.Burger see the example provided in the docs: https://codepen.io/alvarotrigo/pen/rVZWrR